# How to insert records into SQL Server when multiple models are in one view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in SQL Server, *table1* and *table2*. Using the following MODEL, CONTROLLER, and VIEW, I am able to display records from table1 and table2 at www.example.com/Table/Details/1.

MODEL

```
namespace example.Models
{    
    public class table1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string column1{ get; set; }
    }

    public class table2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string column1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class tables
    {
        public IEnumerable<table1> table1{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<table2> table2{ get; set; }
    }

    public class example_db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<table1> foo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table2> bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace example.com.Controllers
{
    public class ContentController : Controller
    {
        private example_db db = new example_db();

        //GET: Content/Details/1
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new example_db())
            {
                var model = new tables()
                {
                    table1 = db.table1.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList(),
                    table2 = db.table2.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).ToList()
                };
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@model example.Models.tables

@foreach (var item in Model.table1)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.column1)
}

@foreach (var item in Model.table2)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.column1)
}
```

At www.example.com/Content/Details/1, data from table1 and table2 is displayed. In this example, **foo** is in *table1*, and **bar** is in *table2*.

[image]

I want to add a form at www.example.com/Content/Details/1 that will insert a record into table2. I have added this to the CONTROLLER:

```
    // POST: Content/Details/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "id,column1")] tables tables)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.table2.Add(tables);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(tables);
    }
```

When attempting to build the project in Visual Studio, this error displays: CS1503 Argument1: cannot convert from 'www.example.com.Models.tables' to 'www.example.com.Models.table2'

[image]

I am not sure how to adjust the CONTROLLER so that I can insert records into table2.

**EDIT**:

I have tried the following in my CONTROLLER (Captial "T" in *Tables*).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(Tables tables)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.table2.Add(tables.table2);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(tables);
}
```

When building the project, I get this error: CS1061 'tables' does not contain a definition for 'table2' and no extension method 'table2' accepting a first argument of type 'tables' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

I have tried the following in my CONTROLLER (Lower case "t" in *tables*).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(tables tables)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.table2.Add(tables.table2);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(tables);
}
```

When building the project, I get this error: CS1061 'tables' does not contain a definition for 'table2' and no extension method 'table2' accepting a first argument of type 'tables' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

I have tried the following in my CONTROLLER (Captial "T" in *Table2*).

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "id,column1")] Table2 table2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.table2.Add(table2);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(tables);
    }
```

When building the project, I get this error: 'tables' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

[image]

I have tried the following in my CONTROLLER (Lower case "t" in *table2*).

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "id,column1")] table2 table2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.table2.Add(table2);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(tables);
    }
```

When building the project, I get this error: CS0246 The type or namespace 'table2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are new to C# itself.. You'll need to add each table records separately from `tables`, like `db.table1.addRange(tables.table1)` and so on...

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. I have added EDIT to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are getting error at line "db.table2.Add(tables)".

db.table2 is DbSet of type "table2" so you can only add object of "table2" to it. While you are trying to add object of "tables" class. This is clear case of type mismatch.

The correct line of code for you would be.

```
db.table1.Add(tables.table1);
 db.table2.Add(tables.table2);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

You also would need to change the signature of your Action method as following.

```
public ActionResult Details(tables tables)
```

If you are expecting only data of table2 to be posted from UI, then you need to change your Action method as following.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(Bind(Include = "id,column1")] table2 table2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.table2.Add(table2);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // You need to re-create object to tables class to pass it to the view.
    return View(tables);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have added EDIT to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your updates.

Your tables class does not have property table2. It has two propertis with the same name "table1".

```
public IEnumerable<table1> table1{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<table1> table1{ get; set; }
```

I am not sure why compiler did not show error about that.

You have to change second property to as following in tables class.

```
public IEnumerable<table2> table2{ get; set; }
```

Now about error that "type or namespace 'tables' could not be found', you need to see the comment which I put in my solution. The comment is

// You need to re-create object to tables class to pass it to the view.

So you need to create new object "tables" of class "tables" to pass to the view.

Your code is also confusing because you have used same name for class, property and object.
Changing one letter from lower case to upper case will not solve any issue. It will increase numebr of compile errors.

These are all simple C# compile time errors and they reason behind them are very clear if one have proper understanding of C# and OOP.

Comment: That you Chetan. I have corrected the classes in my model. I made a grammatical error. It is working now. Thank you very much for the help!